# How to match projection to IGC file format in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I am building an OpenLayers application. There are circles along the map and the IGC file is supposed to show that the track touches the circles. However, from the image below it is not the case. [image]

The track in question was verified to enter the circles via other methods, so the issue appears to be different coordinate systems or projections.

In the code below I define the circle with

```
var MAGMA = new ol.geom.Circle(ol.proj.transform([-111.5032, 33.1356], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), 5000);
```

The IGC portion of the code is

```
var igcUrls = [
track1.igc',
];
function get(url, callback) {
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', url);
client.onload = function() {
callback(client.responseText);
};
client.send();
}
var igcFormat = new ol.format.IGC();
for (var i = 0; i < igcUrls.length; ++i) {
get(igcUrls[i], function(data) {
var features = igcFormat.readFeatures(data,
{featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});
vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
});
```

If I change the `featueProjection: 'EPSG:3857'` to `'featueProjection: 'EPSG:4326'` then the IGC track disappears from the page. I am most certain that the issue is a mismatch in projections, as the IGC file uses WGS-1984, but I cannot figure out how to correct it.

The ol.map is here. Adding `projection: 'EPSG:4326'` to the `ol.view` causes the map to not render properly.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource,
      style: styleFunction
    }),

    vectorLineLayer,
    vectorLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: whartonMercator,
    zoom: 9,
  })
});
```

The original code was found here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/igc/Clement-Latour.igc

Comment: The Circle object is the issue.  Its radius isn't really in meters.  You can draw one using the method from [moveable-type.co.uk](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), that might work better.

Comment: for relatively small circles adjusting the radius for the projection's point resolution at the center might be sufficient
`var magmaCenter = ol.proj.transform([-111.5032, 33.1356], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
var MAGMA = new ol.geom.Circle(magmaCenter, 5000/ol.proj.getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, magmaCenter));`

Comment: I tired `var magmaCenter = ol.proj.transform([-111.5032, 33.1356], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'); var MAGMA = new ol.geom.Circle(magmaCenter, 5000/ol.proj.getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, magmaCenter));` but the map does not get rendered. Am I missing something?